# Softlayer API for getting list of devices in VLAN

Tags: rest

How do I get the list of devices which are assigned to VLANs in Softlayer?
How to get the list of devices attached to that VLAN?

[SL portal shows the devices on vlan i want the rest api for getting those devices list or devices count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryXF6.png)

Comment: You need to provide more details about your question.

Comment: can you check the latest picture i have uploaded?